# Dom Navigation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

How can i access 3rd Element(H2) starting with the parent element "id="services-list".

Iam currently accessing using the below method.Is there a better way to do apart from the below. Please see i need purely Javascript.

```
var z = document.querySelectorAll('section[id="services-list"]');
z[0].firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.textContent


<section id="services-list" class="section container ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-6 offset-md-1">
            <h2 class="section__title">Services</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Regards,
Sree

Comment: use class selector instead as you have a `class=''section__title"` with `h2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let el = document.getElementById("services-list").getElementsByTagName("h2")[0];

console.log(el);
```

or with getElementsByClassName (but EI8- doesn't support getElementsByClassName)

```
let el = document.getElementById("services-list").getElementsByClassName("section__title")[0];

console.log(el);
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById("")` to get the section.

Starting from this DOM element you can now call `getElementsByClassName("")` to find the `h2` element

```js
const elem = document.getElementById("services-list").getElementsByClassName("section__title")[0];

console.log(elem);
```

```html
<section id="services-list" class="section container ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-6 offset-md-1">
            <h2 class="section__title">Services</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `.querySelectorAll(''#services-list .row .col-12 h2.section__title')` or even `.querySelectorAll('#services-list h2.section__title')` is a better way

Comment: @Rajesh Why is it a better way ?

Comment: Because you are getting one element and then searching for className in this fetched element. Its better to merge both operation. Also `getElementsByClassName("section__title")[0];` will not guarantee that the element is an `h2` element and also does not handles for the case when there are multiple elements with same class

Comment: @Rajesh Ok but why is it better ? Is your way faster than mine ? Do you say it is better because you think it looks easier ?

Comment: I'm sorry if I have offended you. Also I have not tested it yet for performance, but doing 2 operations would/ should take more time

Comment: I am not offended. I am trying to understand you. I don't understand why you are saying it is better. I just think that it is another way of answering the question

Comment: Hey basically means that your code relies on a valid result returned from all `getElementById("services-list")` and `.getElementsByClassName("section__title")` as well as `[0]`. If any of these fail, there will be errors while his suggestion needs less checks since he only queries for ALL the selectors at once and does not rely on functions and indexes to do the finding.

Comment: @DrColossos You are right ! I did not think about errors managing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use complicated selectors to achieve your goal

```js
var z = document.querySelectorAll('section[id="services-list"] .section__title');
console.log (z[0].textContent)
```

```html
<section id="services-list" class="section container ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-6 offset-md-1">
            <h2 class="section__title">Services</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

If you want to learn how to select elements in a shorter way:

```js
var z = window['services-list'] // you id is unique, so we can use shorter way to select it 
        .querySelector('h2'); // you have only one h2 inside, so we also can do is shorter
console.log (z.textContent)
```

```html
<section id="services-list" class="section container ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-6 offset-md-1">
            <h2 class="section__title">Services</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```